# Type Conversion Error using For-Each Loop

Tags: java

I'm getting this error on my for-each loop:

> "Type mismatch: Cannot convert from element type Object to Employee"

```
private static HashMap<Integer,Employee> employeeDatabase = new HashMap<Integer,Employee>();

public HashMap getEmployeeDatabase() {
    return employeeDatabase;
}

for(Employee e: c.getEmployeeDatabase().values()) 
    {
        e.print();
    }
```

If it matters - 'Employee' contains int(id),String(name),double(salary). The int(id) is copied for use as the Integer key for my HashMap when the HashMap is populated.

Edit: The issue was with the getEmployeeDatabase accessor returning a raw type, thank you to those who answered.

For those wondering about 'c' variable:

```
Company c = new Company();
```

That's where it came from. The Company class default constructor uses a private method to populate employeeDatabase from Scanner.

Comment: Return type `HashMap` is a *raw* generic. DO NOT use *raw* generics. Specify the correct type parameters, i.e. `HashMap<Integer,Employee>`

Comment: can you show your complete code?

Answer (score 3):

Your method return type is the [***raw type***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Don't use **raw types**.

```
private static HashMap<Integer,Employee> employeeDatabase = new HashMap<Integer,Employee>();

public HashMap getEmployeeDatabase() {
    return employeeDatabase;
}
```

Should be something like

```
private static Map<Integer, Employee> employeeDatabase = new HashMap<>();

public Map<Integer, Employee> getEmployeeDatabase() {
    return employeeDatabase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you dont specify generics, Object is assumed, then

```
public HashMap getEmployeeDatabase()
```

Is actually

```
public HashMap<Object, Object> getEmployeeDatabase()
```

So

```
for(Employee e : c.getEmployeeDatabase().values()) {
    e.print();
}
```

Is incorrect because values() will return

```
Collection<Object>
```